# Ayuda Base de Datos SQL de Hana

Tags: sql, sap, base-de-datos, hana

Buen día,
Agradecería su ayuda si fuera posible, Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT T1."Segment_0"||'-'||T1."Segment_1"||'-'||T1."Segment_2" as "Cuenta",    
T1."AcctName",   
sum   (T0."Debit"-T0."Credit")as "Saldo_SOL",


(
SELECT  SUM(T0."VALOR") AS preSUPUESTO FROM (
SELECT "U_EXC_CTACONT", '1' AS "MES" ,"U_EXC_ENERO" AS "VALOR" , "U_EXC_CCOSTO" AS "COSTO"FROM "@EXC_PRESUPUESTO1"    WHERE  "Code"=  YEAR('2020')
UNION ALL
SELECT "U_EXC_CTACONT", '2' AS "MES" ,"U_EXC_FEBRERO" AS "VALOR" , "U_EXC_CCOSTO" AS "COSTO"FROM "@EXC_PRESUPUESTO1"   WHERE  "Code"=  YEAR('2020')
UNION ALL
SELECT "U_EXC_CTACONT", '3' AS "MES" ,"U_EXC_MARZO" AS "VALOR", "U_EXC_CCOSTO" AS "COSTO" FROM "@EXC_PRESUPUESTO1"  WHERE  "Code"=  YEAR('2020')
) AS T0    

WHERE T0."MES" >= MONTH('20200101') AND T0."MES"<= MONTH('20200131')
AND  "U_EXC_CTACONT"= T1."Segment_0"||'-'||T1."Segment_1"||'-'||T1."Segment_2"        
GROUP BY T0."U_EXC_CTACONT"
) AS PRESUPUESTO



FROM JDT1 T0  
INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0."Account" = T1."AcctCode"

WHERE T0."RefDate" BETWEEN '20200101' AND '20200131'
AND T0."ProfitCode" = '10501'


AND SUBSTRING (T1."FormatCode",12,4)!='9410'
group by T1."Segment_0"||'-'||T1."Segment_1"||'-'||T1."Segment_2", T1."AcctName"
order by 1
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado del mes de **Enero**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando 3 tablas
**OACT  -
JDT1 -
EXC_PRESUPUESTO1**

Columna **Saldo_SOL** = Consulta Principal

Columna **PRESUPUESTO**= Subconsulta

El inconveniente que tengo es que en la Columna de la subconsulta  **presupuesto** no me aparecen todos los registros ya que la columna **Saldo_Sol** no tiene valores para el numero de cuenta que si tiene el presupuesto.
Solo me esta priorizando los valores del campo **Saldo_SOL** dejándome sin los valores que tiene la columna **Presupuesto**

ambas tablas están relacionadas con el código de la columna **Cuenta**

Como puedo hacer para que me muestre todos los registros de la subconsulta **PRESUPUESTO** que tienen datos y en la Columna **Saldo_Sol** me aparezca **Cero**

**Ejemplo**

Digamos que me faltan Estas cuentas pero no aparecen por que no tienen datos en Saldo_SOL y Si en Presupuesto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: con un left join?

Comment: mas bien un full inner, si lo que necesita son todos los registros, comunes y no comunes

Comment: Disculpa como podría hacer un full inner join a la subconsulta

Answer (score 1):

Creo que deberías usar un LEFT JOIN.
Ejemplo:

```
LEFT JOIN OACT T1 ON T0."Account" = T1."AcctCode"
```